# Clients without Isstandard() function

Tags: transactions, client

Are there any bitcoin clients without the Isstandard () function which would allow non standard transactions to be broadcast?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about any client that removed standardness checks altogether. However there exists some alternate clients with different default policy settings, such as [Bitcoin Knots](https://bitcoinknots.org/).